# Find out how Abstractly Capacious™ someone is!

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

At the Code-Golf™ Psychological Society, you are delighted to present a new method of measuring mental age: *Abstract Capacity™*.

To get the *Abstract Capacity* of a person, you take their actual age divided by 4, take their IQ divided by 9, then add the two values together. Then, round this sum down to find the *Abstract Capacity*.

**Challenge**

Write a program, given an actual age *A* and an IQ of *I*, produces the *Abstract Capacity* using those values. The program should also print how older (age) or how smarter (IQ) someone should be in order to raise their *Abstract Capacity* by 1.

An input will always look something like

> *A* *I*

and an output will always look something like

> *AC* *A'* *I'*

where AC, A' and I' respectively denote the *Abstract Capacity*, how older someone has to be to raise their *Abstract Capacity*, and how smarter someone has to be to raise their *Abstract Capacity*.

**Examples**

**Input**

```
13 43
```

**Output**

```
8 4 9
```

**Input**

```
92 5
```

**Output**

```
23 2 4
```

**Input**

```
40 17
```

**Output**

```
11 1 1
```

**Rules**

Your code must be able to find the *Abstract Capacity* for any given *A* and *I* when 1 < *A*,*I* < 400.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: *You can only use one of the languages commonly pre-installed on Mac such as C, C++, Java, PhP, Perl, Python (2 or 3), Ruby, and Swift.* - I strongly suggest allowing **any** language to compete.

Comment: Also, some more test cases would be helpful in order to test our submissions.

Comment: If I am not wrong, by increasing `43` by `7`, you get `14/4+50/9` which is higher than `9` (i.e. `9.0(5)`). If the expected result is always `int(a/4+i/9 + 1)`, then the whole answer would be `[int(a/4+i/9),4,9]` for all cases.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You put 14/4 instead of 13/4. I can confirm that 13/4+50/9>9. Also, I've edited the question in line with your previous suggestions.

Comment: Now that you have removed the restriction, I upvoted this challenge

Comment: Can we choose the order of the output or does it have to be `AC, A', I'`?

Comment: @Emigna You'll have to use that order, to make it fair on everyone else.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that only I would get to choose the output order of course. I just felt it was worth asking as that would have saved me a byte and maybe would have helped someone else as well. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Emigna Oh yeah, I understand. just answered in a way that I felt would justify my choice, not pointing fingers at you in any shape or form. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

```python
def f(a,i):r=a*9+i*4;print r/36,(r+44-i*4)/9-a,(r+39-a*9)/4-i
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI1EnU9OqyDZRy1I7U8vEuqAoM69EoUjf2ExHo0jbxEQXKKipb6mbCOIaA2ktS019oOj/NA1DYx0TY83/AA)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder (`print` instead of `return`).

```python
def f(a,i):x=a*9+i*4;m=x%36;print x/36,4-m/9,9-m/4
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY07DoMwEAVrOMU2iN8iYuwgGQR3WSk42QKDLArn9I4DBc0U86R5@/f4bLYL4bUYMAUhl4OfqNI1V2pcJ5/Jftwd2wN8K3tUzdpq1JEqmM0BAVtwZN9LISR2ohzS5O/59koiiOcj4lyTq0YIjJA3c47RXc/hBw)**

Comment: Switch to `print` to save 1 byte?

Comment: Oh yeah - I always assumed we could only print the result if it is a full program, while a function must actually yield the result. Do you know if there is a consensus?

Comment: I have used it many times without problems. I don't know if there is any consensus.

Comment: [Here's the consensus.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2457/68615)

Comment: Ah cool, thanks @totallyhuman!

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>67</s> 50 bytes

```js
f=
(a,i,r=a*9+i*4)=>[r/36|0,4-(r%36/9|0),9-(r%36>>2)]
```

```html
<div oninput=[ac.textContent,ea.textContent,ei.textContent]=f(a.value,i.value)>Age: <input type=number id=a><br>IQ: <input type=number id=i><br>Abstract Capacity: <span id=ac></span><br>Extra age needed: <span id=ea></span><br>Extra IQ needed: <span id=ei>
```

Edit: Although originally I was trying to verify @Mr.Xcoder's comment I ended up verifying @JonathanAllan's answer instead.

Comment: 61 bytes: `(a,i,r=(a*9+i*4))=>[r/36|0,(r+44-i*4)/9-a|0,(r+39-a*9)/4-i|0]`. Not 100% sure it is correct, but I believe it is

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
/K+*9Q*4E36-4/J%K36 9-9/J4
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FK%2B%2a9Q%2a4E36-4%2FJ%25K36+9-9%2FJ4&input=13%0A43+&debug=0)**

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
K9hGy/sktQ3M1YS-b*XkG-
```

-3 bytes thanks to @LuisMendo

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39syw71Svzi7JNDY1zAyWDdJKyLbXff//2hLIwXTWAA)

Comment: `[4 9]` can be shortened to `K9h`, and `tGw` to `Gy`: [`K9hGy/sktQ3M1YS-b*XkG-`](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39syw71Svzi7JNDY1zAyWDdJKyLbXff//2hLIwXTWAA)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
94S©*O36‰RĆÁ®÷®RαÁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v8wNWFiMWX//zk0U8KpKk8zNuKAsFLEhsOBwq7Dt8KuUs6xw4H//1s5MiwgNV0)

**Explanation**

Example for `input = [92, 5]`

```
94                   # push the number 94
  S©                 # split to a list of digits and store a copy in register
                     # STACK: [9,4]
    *                # element-wise multiplication with input
                     # STACK: [828, 20]
     O               # sum
                     # STACK: 848
      36‰            # divmod 36
                     # STACK: [23, 20]
         R           # reverse
          Ć          # append the head (the mod result)
           Á         # rotate right
                     # STACK: [20, 20, 23]
            ®÷       # element-wise integer division with the register
                     # STACK: [2, 5, 23]
              ®Rα    # absolute difference with the register reversed
                     # STACK: [2, 4, 23]
                 Á   # rotate right
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 89 bytes

```
=INT(A2/4+B2/9)&" "&ROUNDUP(4-MOD(A2*9+B2*4,36)/9,0)&" "&ROUNDUP(9-MOD(A2*9+B2*4,36)/4,0)
```

Using @Jonathan Allan's approach.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>77</s> 67 bytes

Nicked from @JonathanAllan

```
a->i->System.out.printf("%d %d %d",(i=a*9+i*4)/36,4-i/9%4,9-i/4%9);
```

Comment: 67 bytes: `a->i->System.out.printf("%d %d %d",(i=a*9+i*4)/36,4-i/9%4,9-i/4%9);`.